# how to combine multiple pictures to get a 3D image

Tags: iphone, xcode, 3d

how to combine multiple pictures to get a 3D image, please help

I need to combine multiple pictures to get a 3D image. by turning this picture, either left to right or the other way around, it shows details.

Comment: These pictures? Which pictures?

Comment: multiple PICTURES taken from camera